# "To hear" or "to hearing"?

Tags: verbs

I often see constructions like this one:

> I look forward to hearing from you soon.

It seems a little strange to me. In my mind it would look better using the infinitive form "to hear". I don't know if it has something with the verbals... Anyway, what I want to know is which form is correct and why?

Comment: This is a good question. Non-native speakers are often tripped up by the fact that *to* is both the infinitive marker and a regular preposition, but only in the latter case can it be followed by a participle.

Comment: Compare 'I look forward to Christmas'; here, the 'to' is obviously not the infinitive-marker. Though arguments from analogy are often risky, here it is valid. 'Look forward to' is a transitive multi-word verb, with reasonable overlap with the synonym '[can't] wait for', where 'to', like 'for', is a transitivising particle.

Comment: Here, OP seems to be keen to know if he can use ...."I look forward to hear from you soon....', or it should always be '...I look forward to hearing from you...' (.)  Even I have this doubt. Often we omit 'I' or 'We', but just write "Look forward to hearing from you...." or even "Looking forward to hearing from you...", where two 'ing' forms occur.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not an infinitive. "Hearing from you soon" is a gerund, which functions as a noun.

> I look forward to [hearing from you soon].

is the same kind of construction as

> I look forward to [my vacation].

Comment: ...or, to get rid of the confounding 'to', "I await hearing from you soon."

Comment: +1!  Although I do prefer _I am looking forward to_ in some situations.  For no real reason!

Answer (score 7):

If it were an infinitive, you'd be correct - it would have to be "to hear." But in this sentence, *to* isn't functioning as part of an infinitive, but simply as a preposition. That has to be followed by a noun or a nominal phrase, and "hearing" is a noun.

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically speaking, a thing being looked forward to (*hearing* in this case) should be a noun. Parse it here as *the experience of hearing* if that makes any more sense to you.

But even though it's a stock phrase in business letters, it *is* a somewhat odd choice of words for its normal context, where invariably the anticipated event will be *reading*, rather than *hearing*.

Comment: Two things: 1. "hearing" is a noun in this case (a gerund). 2. It's a set-phrase, that is, you "hear from someone" when you receive communication from them, no matter if you used your ears or not. Presumably this goes back before the rise of written communication.

Comment: 1. Well that's what I thought I said - I just thought that adding the actual word *gerund* was an unnecessary detail. 2. Maybe *hear from* does indeed predate writing - but it's still a bit odd. Like a blind person saying "Nice to see you" (which they do all the time, obviously).