# Start save money or start saving money?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is it right to say "Start save money..." 
or it should be start saving money?

and how the continuation of a such sentence after that could be... 
I mean, which of the following are correct sentences:

- Start save money and help people
- Start saving money and help people
- Start saving money and helping people

Comment: Hi @FFrewin, Welcome to EL&U. Your question seems too basic for this community. Why not ask them on our sister site [ell](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) ? They're a more suitable choice for beginners.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal - thanks - can you post the link to the site... because it doesn't appear in your comment.

Comment: yes, I have already created a hyperlink to that site with the word 'ell' in my first comment and funny, it's working on my system. Anyways, http://ell.stackexchange.com/ ! Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Started to work” vs “Started working”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/started-to-work-vs-started-working).

Comment: @Rathony, basic question for the site yes - but I don't think it's a duplicate to the one you mentioned.

Comment: @FFrewin I didn't mean it is the 100% duplicate. People do have a different opinion and the adjective *possible* is used for that reason. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is ungrammatical. But you could say *Start **to save** money and help people*

The second and third are both grammatical, but they have fine differences in meaning.

Number 2 means *Start saving money and **(hence, by that action)** help people*.

Number 3 means *Start saving money and **(also start)** helping people*.