# Why was "to + verb + ing" used in this case?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, infinitives, gerunds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use “to + V-ing”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing)
>   [“To hear” or “to hearing”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing)

> Samson had been a strong man prior to ***having*** his hair cut.

From a grammatical point of view, when *to* appears before a verb, it indicates that the infinitive (simple) form of the verb is to be used. But I have seen *to* used with conjugated forms of verb as well. What is the explanation for such uses?

For instance, why is this not correct?

> Samson had been a strong man prior to ***his hair are*** being cut?

Comment: imho this is basic grammar "General Reference". The first example is perfectly standard English.

Comment: I think this is a good question as it illustrates the many different tenses in use in the English language. In this case, "before he had his hair cut", "prior to cutting his hair", "before his hair was cut", and "prior to his hair being cut", and "prior to his having his hair cut" are all correct, but each way of stating this has slightly different implications.

Comment: True. But I think the confusion came from confusing a string with a constituent. It would be clear in speech, but writing omits the intonation and rhythm bands that carry this information.

Answer (score 11):

The *to* in this sentence is **not** the [Infinitive Complementizer *to*](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/complmnt.html). It's the **Preposition** *to*, part of the complex preposition *prior to*, which means the same as *before*:

- *Samson had been a strong man **prior to** having his hair cut.*
- *Samson had been a strong man **before** having his hair cut.*

So the gerund clause *having his hair cut* is the object of the preposition *prior to*.

In other words, *to having* is not a ***Constituent*** of this sentence; *to* is part of the constituent *prior to,* and *having* is part of the constituent *having his hair cut*. They just happen to be next to each other here.

> Not every infinitive is marked with *to*; not every *to* marks an infinitive.
> **Constituents**, not strings.

---

**Addendum**. The reason why

- **Samson had been a strong man prior to his hair are being cut.*

is ungrammatical is because the gerund phrase requires a gerund, and *are* is not a gerund.

Apparently there is some confusion here between the **Progressive** construction, which uses a tensed form of *be* plus the *-ing* form; and the **Gerund** construction, which is untensed and requires no auxiliary verb, just the *-ing* form. These are two uses of [the *-ing* form](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gerund.html) of the verb.

Comment: I'm going to add an addendum to this because I realize I didn't specifically address why _*Samson had been a strong man prior to his hair are being cut_ is ungrammatical.