# Looking forward to " see" or "seeing"?

Tags: verbs, nouns, sense-verbs, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which of the  2 sentences is correct?

Sam is looking forward to see the Rocky mountains.

Sam is looking forward to seeing the Rocky mountains.

Comment: What do dictionaries suggest? - http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/look+forward#look_1__225

Comment: "To see the Rocky Mountains is something Sam looks forward to" is also a possibility. Don

Comment: possible duplicate of ["To hear" or "to hearing"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing)

Answer (score 5):

In the example you gave, "to seeing" is correct. To understand why, let's think about different meanings of the word *to*.

- *To* can be part of a verb in the infinitive: "To be or not to be,..." or "I can't wait to see the Rocky Mountains."  The *to* is part of the action.
- *To* can also be a preposition, a word that demonstrates a relationship with something.  Here that something is "seeing the Rocky Mountains", it's what Sam is looking forward *to* — *seeing* is a thing, it is a noun.

By the way, the M in "Rocky Mountains" should be capitalized, it's part of the place name.

Comment: Could you show us how *"seeing"* is a noun and not a verb in the expression "to seeing the Rocky Mountains"?