# ”We're looking forward to helping you find X” vs “We look forward to help you find X” etc

Tags: verbs, progressive-aspect, bare-infinitive, present-progressive

I’m trying to link the following items into a single sentence:

- we
- look forward to
- help you
- find X

So *for example*, here are some ways I was thinking of doing that:

- We look forward to help you find X.
- We’re looking forward to help you find X.
- We’re looking forward to helping you find X.

Well, you get the gist. I'm just unsure how to approach this issue.

Comment: The most common form, in US English, isn't listed - *We look forward to helping you find X.*

Comment: possible duplicate of ["To hear" or "to hearing"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing)

Comment: Is cuz i bettr at English now. (Not really. Just hit the wrong button.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on English grammar, after *looking forward to*, you're supposed to use the verb with *-ing*, so all the items from that list will be crossed off except #2 and #5; that are both the same as far as I can see. So that's how you should have all those phrases in one sentence.

Regarding your question about using *are*, the answer is yes! If the verb comes in *-ing* form, then you do need the *to be* verb beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

The expression “look forward to,” if what you are looking forward to is to be expressed in a verb, *requires* the gerund, an *-ing* form of that verb, to be the object of the preposition *to*—in this case *helping.* Since that *-ing* form is necessary, it might be better *not* to use an *-ing* form of the verb *look* as well: that is, use “We look forward to helping you find *x”* rather than “We are looking forward to helping you find *x,”* though both are perfectly grammatical. If you follow this advice, then you do *not* use an *are.* This version is not among your enumerated examples.